# Why the statement exec("php -l $file", $error, $exit) set $exit = 5 while there's no error?

Tags: php, web

The file exists. I'm just validating the syntax of the file with this statement.

```
exec("php -l $file", $error, $exit);
```

It is supposed to set $exit = 0 if there's no error. In other words, the syntax in the file is right. However in my case, it sets $exit as 5 and $error as empty array. I wonder how this is the case. Thanks in advance.

Also, I'm using MAMP. PHP5.3. $file is the hash string of a file content. $code is the string of the file content gotten by file_get_contents() function. I don't think $translatedFile and $error matter in my question.

```
function validateSyntax($code,$translatedFile,  &$error){
        $translatedFile = $this->getTranslatedLanguageFile($translatedFile);
        $file = 'cache/'.md5(time());
        file_put_contents( $file, $code);
        exec("php -l $file",$error,$exit);
        foreach($error as $k=>$v){
            $error[$k] = str_replace($file, $translatedFile, $v);
        }
        unlink($file);
        if($retcode==0)return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your quotes are mis-matched if you intended `$exit` to be the third param of `exec()`.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious.. what's in `$file`?

Answer (score 1):

You are quoting around all of the parameters, rather than just using quotes around the command and passing the last two arguments. You are most likely looking for

```
exec("php -l $file", $error, $exit);
```